# Change Text Color as Image changes or with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what I have done so far.

```css
.grid {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em 0 4em;
    max-width: 1000px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Common style */
 .grid figure {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    width: 48%;
    /*background: #3085a3;*/
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.grid figure img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*opacity: 0.8;*/
}
.grid figure figcaption {
    padding: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.grid figure figcaption::before, .grid figure figcaption::after {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.grid figure figcaption, .grid figure figcaption > a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/* Anchor will cover the whole item by default */

/* For some effects it will show as a button */
 .grid figure figcaption > a {
    z-index: 1000;
    text-indent: 200%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.grid figure h2 {
    /*word-spacing: -0.15em;*/
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family:sans-serif, serif;
}
.grid figure h2 span {
    /*font-weight: 800;*/
}
.grid figure h2, .grid figure p {
    margin: 0;
}
.grid figure p {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 68.5%;
    font-family:serif;
}
/* Change Images of Home Page */
 @-webkit-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
#cf3 img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
#cf3 img.top {
    -webkit-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -moz-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -o-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-duration: 5s;
    -o-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
/* Change Images of Home Page */

/*---------------*/

/***** Lexi *****/

/*---------------*/
 figure.effect-lexi {
    /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000 0%,#fff 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #000 0%,#fff 100%);*/
}
figure.effect-lexi img {
    margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
    max-width: none;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% + 10px);
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
figure.effect-lexi figcaption::before, figure.effect-lexi p {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
}
figure.effect-lexi figcaption::before {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    bottom: -100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 900px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    content:'';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
figure.effect-lexi:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
figure.effect-lexi h2 {
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(5px, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(5px, 5px, 0);
}
figure.effect-lexi p {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 1.5em 1.5em 0;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(20px, 20px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(20px, 20px, 0);
}
figure.effect-lexi:hover figcaption::before {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
figure.effect-lexi:hover h2, figure.effect-lexi:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
figure.effect-chocolate {
    /*background: #DAD9D1;*/
    height:466px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
      <figure class="effect-lexi effect-chocolate">
       <div id="cf3" class="shadow">
        <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/22.jpg" alt="Image" class = "bottom" />
        <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/21.jpg" alt="Image" class = "top" />
       </div>
       <figcaption>
        <h2>Dark <span>Chocolate Smoothie</span></h2>
        <p>Description</p>
        <a href="#">View more</a>
       </figcaption>   
      </figure>
     </div>
```

Here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/askxgdrw/).

For changing image I have used CSS animation.
Now what I want to do is change color of Text over image as image changes.

How to do it?
Any Help is much appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: how you are changing image same you can change text-color also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give another animation to h2 called  `textFadeInOut`

```
@-webkit-keyframes textFadeInOut {   // add other browser prefixes too
     0% {
         color: green;
     }          
     100% {
         color: yellow;
     }
  }
```

And add this animation to `figure.effect-lexi h2`

```css
.grid {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em 0 4em;
    max-width: 1000px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Common style */
 .grid figure {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    width: 48%;
    /*background: #3085a3;*/
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.grid figure img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*opacity: 0.8;*/
}
.grid figure figcaption {
    padding: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.grid figure figcaption::before, .grid figure figcaption::after {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.grid figure figcaption, .grid figure figcaption > a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/* Anchor will cover the whole item by default */

/* For some effects it will show as a button */
 .grid figure figcaption > a {
    z-index: 1000;
    text-indent: 200%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.grid figure h2 {
    /*word-spacing: -0.15em;*/
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family:sans-serif, serif;
}
.grid figure h2 span {
    /*font-weight: 800;*/
}
.grid figure h2, .grid figure p {
    margin: 0;
}
.grid figure p {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 68.5%;
    font-family:serif;
}
/* Change Images of Home Page */
 @-webkit-keyframes textFadeInOut {
    0% {
        color: green;
    }
  
    100% {
        color: yellow;
    }
}
 @-webkit-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
#cf3 img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}

#cf3 img.top {
    -webkit-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -moz-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -o-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-duration: 5s;
    -o-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
figure.effect-lexi h2 {
    -webkit-animation-name: textFadeInOut ;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -moz-animation-name: textFadeInOut ;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -o-animation-name: textFadeInOut ;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-duration: 5s;
    -o-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-name: textFadeInOut ;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
/* Change Images of Home Page */

/*---------------*/

/***** Lexi *****/

/*---------------*/
 figure.effect-lexi {
    /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000 0%,#fff 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #000 0%,#fff 100%);*/
}
figure.effect-lexi img {
    margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
    max-width: none;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% + 10px);
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
figure.effect-lexi figcaption::before, figure.effect-lexi p {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
}
figure.effect-lexi figcaption::before {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    bottom: -100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 900px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    content:'';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
figure.effect-lexi:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
figure.effect-lexi h2 {
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(5px, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(5px, 5px, 0);
}
figure.effect-lexi p {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 1.5em 1.5em 0;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(20px, 20px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(20px, 20px, 0);
}
figure.effect-lexi:hover figcaption::before {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
figure.effect-lexi:hover h2, figure.effect-lexi:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
figure.effect-chocolate {
    /*background: #DAD9D1;*/
    height:466px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
   <figure class="effect-lexi effect-chocolate">
 <div id="cf3" class="shadow">
  <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/22.jpg" alt="Image" class = "bottom" />
  <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/21.jpg" alt="Image" class = "top" />
 </div>
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Dark <span>Chocolate Smoothie</span></h2>
      <p>Description</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>   
   </figure>
 </div>
```

Comment: This Works perfect. +1 For This. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution using JQuery UI:

add an id to your h2:

```
<h2 id="yourText">Dark <span>Chocolate Smoothie</span></h2>
```

change the color of the text using an JQuery UI animation:

```
var timeOffset = 2500;
var changeTime = 2500;

function changeImage() {
    if (red) {
        $("#yourText").animate({
            "color": "#fff"
        }, changeTime, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                changeImage();
            }, timeOffset);
        });
    } else {
        $("#yourText").animate({
            "color": "#f00"
        }, changeTime, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                changeImage();
            }, timeOffset);
        });
    }
    red = !red;
}

setTimeout(function(){changeImage();}, timeOffset);
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markai/szLpqwdt/)

NOTE: the set times are not perfect, you might need to experiment a little to figure out the right timing

Comment: anpsmn's answer is actually better

Comment: Thanks. Earlier answer also worked. And can't accept two answers. But +1 for this short and sweet answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `color` property in css

I added the line at

```
figure.effect-lexi:hover h2, figure.effect-lexi:hover p {
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/askxgdrw/1/)

Comment: I don't want to change color on hover. Just want to do it normally.

Comment: move the `color` css to the default selector - figure.effect-lexi h2 { color: red; } - http://jsfiddle.net/askxgdrw/2/